# Python probscale to show different marker types when using FacetGrid

Tags: python

I would like to use seaborn FacetGrid with probscale to make probability plot of curves with each curve shown in different hue (color) as well as marker type.
I have tried to use 'hue_kws' argument to specify the marker type but it does not seem to work.
(Reference: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)

```py
import seaborn as sns
import probscale

sns.set()
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

#try to plot probplots faceted to show different distributions by different
#hues and markers, but markers doesn't change
fg = (
    sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, hue='smoker', hue_kws=dict(marker=['o','v']),height=5)
        .map(probscale.probplot, 'total_bill', probax='y')
        .set_ylabels('Probabilities')
        .add_legend()
)
```

I expected marker type will change together with hue (as specified in hue_kws) but the plot only shows different color for each curve but marker remain the same type. 
How do I make the curves' marker type change together with hue?

[Probability Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCuAj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported by `probscale`. You can patch your copy of `...\Lib\site-packages\probscale\viz.py` by inserting the following four lines after line 180 to enable this functionality:

```
## !-- kwarg that only seaborn should use --! ##
_marker = fgkwargs.get('marker', None)
if _marker is not None:
    scatter_kws['marker'] = _marker
```

[image]